# Why is my form_validation not working ? error : Field form are not correctly filled

Tags: php, html, database, forms, codeigniter

I am working on updating a profile information with a prefilled forms using the logged user information using `CodeIgniter`.

My problem is, whatever I put in the forms, the prebuild function `form_validation->run()` returns `true`, which means that the form fields are not correctly filled.
I don't think it has anything to do with my database.

Here is my view:

```
<form action="http://obiwan2.univ-brest.fr/licence/lic85/V1/CodeIgniter/index.php/vendeur/modifier_profil_vendeur" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="uname">Prénom:</label>
        <?php echo'<input type="text" class="form-control" id="cmpt_prenom" placeholder="Entrez votre prenom" name="cmpt_prenom" value="'.$profil_vendeur->Prf_prenom.'">';?>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="uname">Nom:</label>
        <?php echo'<input type="text" class="form-control" id="cmpt_nom" placeholder="Entrez votre nom" name="cmpt_nom" value="'.$profil_vendeur->Prf_nom.'">';?>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="uname">adresse e-mail:</label>
        <?php echo'<input type="email" class="form-control" id="cmpt_email" placeholder="Entrez votre e-mail" name="cmpt_email" value="'.$profil_vendeur->Prf_mail.'">';?>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="pwd">Mot de passe:</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="mdp" placeholder="Entrez votre mot de passe" name="mdp">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="pwd">Confirmation du mot de passe:</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="conf_mdp" placeholder="Confirmez votre mot de passe" name="conf_mdp">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Valider</button>
</form>
```

Here is my controller function i'm using :

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
    if ($mdp1==$mdp2) {
        $this->db_model->update_prf_nom_prenom_mail_vendeur($prenom,$nom,$mail,$mdp1);
    } else {
        $mdp['mdp']=$this->db_model->get_prf_nom_prenom_mail();
        $this->db_model->update_prf_nom_prenom_mail_vendeur($prenom,$nom,$mail,$mdp['mdp']->Cmpt_mdp);
    }
} else {
    if ($this->session->statut=="V") {
        $data['profil_vendeur']=$this->db_model->get_prf_nom_prenom_mail();
        $this->load->view('templates/vendeur_haut');
        echo("Veuillez remplir au moins les champs : Prénom, nom, mail");
        $this->load->view('vendeur_modifications_compte.php',$data);
        $this->load->view('templates/bas');
    }
}
```

Thanks for the time you put in helping me to resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Please add $this->form_validation->set_rules in the controller part.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('cmpt_prenom', 'cmpt_prenom', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('cmpt_nom', 'cmpt_nom', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('cmpt_email', 'cmpt_email', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('mdp', 'mdp', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('conf_mdp', 'conf_mdp', 'required');

if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
    if ($mdp1==$mdp2) {
        $this->db_model->update_prf_nom_prenom_mail_vendeur($prenom,$nom,$mail,$mdp1);
    } else {
        $mdp['mdp']=$this->db_model->get_prf_nom_prenom_mail();
        $this->db_model->update_prf_nom_prenom_mail_vendeur($prenom,$nom,$mail,$mdp['mdp']->Cmpt_mdp);
    }
} else {
    if ($this->session->statut=="V") {
        $data['profil_vendeur']=$this->db_model->get_prf_nom_prenom_mail();
        $this->load->view('templates/vendeur_haut');
        echo("Veuillez remplir au moins les champs : Prénom, nom, mail");
        $this->load->view('vendeur_modifications_compte.php',$data);
        $this->load->view('templates/bas');
    }
}
```